# what is the best way to compress a csv file with many duplicates?

Tags: java, csv, comparison, avro, apache-drill

I'm dealing with some data like the following, the first column is the trade id, the second column is the simulation id(duplicate a lot), the third column is some stupid date also quite duplicated, the forth one is the present value of a trade, mostly it is just 0, but any other value should be quite unique.

***My question would be, is there any way to compress the data to 20% storage of its current size meanwhile supporting look up function?***

I have tried Avro project as a way, it can save 40% storage and support apache drill query, but my boss expect there should be 80% saving.

```
41120634|1554|20150203|-509057.56
40998001|1554|20150203|0
40960705|1554|20150203|0
40998049|1554|20150203|0
41038826|1554|20150203|0
41081136|1554|20150203|-7198152.23
41120653|1554|20150203|-319.436349
41081091|1554|20150203|-4.28520907E+009
41120634|1536|20150227|-528555.02
41038808|1536|20150227|0
40998001|1536|20150227|0
41120634|1556|20150130|-528822.733
40960705|1536|20150227|0
40998049|1536|20150227|0
41038826|1536|20150227|0
```

Comment: LZ77 (gzip) is a streaming compressor.

Comment: Algorithms such as these *work* by exploiting redundancy, so a "stupid date quite duplicated" will be compressed quite heavily.  (The more redundant the data is, the better it works.) In order to support searching and lookup, you might need to "tag" the compressed data in some useful way ... and here's where things could get complicated, and very application-specific. (Maybe it's time to instead very-seriously ask, *"how much do big disk drives cost these days?")* What's the return-on-investment of grabbing for that extra 20%?

Comment: @MikeRobinson, it's not about storage but also send them to another country, simply they want it as small as possible.

Comment: Understood. Quite honestly, I think that gzip's your best bet, although other, "slower, but better" compression alternatives also exist. The bugaboo is going to be how you  support "searching and lookup."

Comment: if you use apache-drill user parquet. it gives maximum compression.

Comment: @anji_rajesh, yes, that's exactly what I want to use, can you please give me more details, many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Drill supports the Parquet file format. Parquet is a columnar based file format that supports columnar compression. This allows Parquet to exploit repeated values in columns to save space. By comparison Avro is a row based file format, so it will not be able to achieve as much compression as Parquet for repeated values in columns. [These guys](https://blog.openbridge.com/how-to-be-a-hero-with-powerful-parquet-google-and-amazon-f2ae0f35ee04) have reported 87% compression of their csv data using parquet. More information about how to use Parquet with apache drill is [here](https://drill.apache.org/docs/parquet-format/).

Also as a side note, the Drill team is working on improvements for Parquet which will probably go into the 1.13 release. I believe a 4x increase in read performance was achieved for Parquet files with the new improvements.